# Is there any online tool or someone who can simplify this MySQL SELECT query?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am coding an autosuggest for a Library's search box and it's extremely slow.
Is there any online tool or anyone willing to help me optimize it?

```
 SELECT *,
       grbc_books.id book_id
FROM   grbc_books
       LEFT JOIN grbc_series
              ON grbc_books.series_id = grbc_series.id
       JOIN grbc_collections
         ON grbc_books.collection_id = grbc_collections.id
       LEFT JOIN grbc_places
              ON grbc_books.place_id = grbc_places.id
       RIGHT JOIN grbc_books_subjects
               ON grbc_books_subjects.book_id = grbc_books.id
       LEFT JOIN grbc_subjects
              ON grbc_books_subjects.subject_id = grbc_subjects.id
       RIGHT JOIN grbc_books_authors
               ON grbc_books_authors.book_id = grbc_books.id
       LEFT JOIN grbc_authors
              ON grbc_books_authors.author_id = grbc_authors.id
                 AND ( ( title LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( subtitle LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( series LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( `subject` LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( `first` LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( `last` LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( place LIKE "%yea%" ) )
GROUP  BY `title`,
          subtitle
ORDER  BY title
LIMIT  10;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what basis u r suggesting the usrs ??

Comment: You're using `LIKE` with wildcard before and after the search term. That will _always_ force full table scan without using indexes. There are other issues such as what hardware you use, what did you do to configure your MySQL etc. I suggest getting paid help for this one, unless you want to spend quite a bit of time learning this yourself.

Comment: what about using regexp search instead of like?

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev - that can't use any indexes either.

Comment: @Vilx yup, but can by faster than like. Anyway, fulltext search should  be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned LIKE probably is your bottleneck. My suggestion is for you to start using MATCH AGAINST rather than a like.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1):

Replace the '*' with the columns you really need...right now you're getting all columns of all tables!

Comment: This isn't the answer and it also makes no sense, removing asterisk and adding column list won't put a dent in query performance.

Comment: Yes it will. Might not be a big dent though.

Answer (score 1):

The primary slowdown here will be the `LIKE '%yea%'` conditions. (Also - shouldn't they be in a `WHERE` clause, instead of the last `LEFT JOIN ... ON...` clause?) The problem with such queries is that MySQL cannot use any indexes to find the necessary rows. It needs to do a full scan every time. The correct solution would be to use a [fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html).

Also, as [Oli suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15269758/41360), removing the `*` might help.

Comment: Assuming they refer to the respective tables - grbc_series, grbc_subjects and grbc_places then sticking them in the WHERE clause will kill the OUTER JOINs, so if OUTER JOINs are what's wanted then they really should each be in their respective JOIN clauses. Also, PhotoPaul, it's unlikely that you want to use RIGHT JOIN in this scenario. What do you think that achieves?

Answer (score 1):

Note that "%yea%" cannot use an index, so will be inefficient, but "yea%" can and is therefore much faster.

And remember that you only need to outer join a table if there's a chance that's there's no associated data within it. I don't know your data structure but for tables like subject and author this seems unlikely.

If I was writing this query, and not switching to use FULLTEXT, then I'd expect it to look like this...

```
 SELECT DISTINCT b.title
               , b.subtitle
               , b.id book_id
   FROM grbc_books b
   JOIN grbc_collections c
     ON c.id = b.collection_id
   JOIN grbc_books_subjects bh
     ON bh.book_id = b.id
   JOIN grbc_subjects h
     ON h.id = bh.subject_id 
   JOIN grbc_books_authors ba  
     ON ba.book_id = b.id
   JOIN grbc_authors a
     ON a.id = ba.author_id 
   LEFT 
   JOIN grbc_series s
     ON s.id = b.series_id
    AND s.series  LIKE "%yea%" 
   LEFT 
   JOIN grbc_places p
     ON p.id = b.place_id 
    AND p.place   LIKE "%yea%" 
  WHERE b.title LIKE "%yea%" 
     OR b.subtitle LIKE "%yea%" 
     OR h.subject LIKE "%yea%" 
     OR a.first LIKE "%yea%" 
     OR a.last LIKE "%yea%" 
  ORDER  
     BY b.title
  LIMIT 10;
```

...however my guess is that this will only have a tiny impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

Full text search is "optimised" by removing a database from the equation. Your options are:

- Solr
- Elastic Search
- Sphinx

Relational database is super slow when it comes down to full text search and you can't do much about it. If you expect a small traffic and you can accept slowness try adding indexes to your text fields. It will make INSERT statement slower in a proportion to amount of data.

Finally, you can troubleshoot your queries by adding "EXPLAIN" before you Statement:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *,
       grbc_books.id book_id
FROM   grbc_books
       LEFT JOIN grbc_series
              ON grbc_books.series_id = grbc_series.id
       JOIN grbc_collections
         ON grbc_books.collection_id = grbc_collections.id
       LEFT JOIN grbc_places
              ON grbc_books.place_id = grbc_places.id
       RIGHT JOIN grbc_books_subjects
               ON grbc_books_subjects.book_id = grbc_books.id
       LEFT JOIN grbc_subjects
              ON grbc_books_subjects.subject_id = grbc_subjects.id
       RIGHT JOIN grbc_books_authors
               ON grbc_books_authors.book_id = grbc_books.id
       LEFT JOIN grbc_authors
              ON grbc_books_authors.author_id = grbc_authors.id
                 AND ( ( title LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( subtitle LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( series LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( `subject` LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( `first` LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( `last` LIKE "%yea%" )
                        OR ( place LIKE "%yea%" ) )
GROUP  BY `title`,
          subtitle
ORDER  BY title
```

If you decide to stay with the database approach consider caching to not repeat queries.